# How old was Theon Greyjoy when he was brought to Winterfell?

Tags: game-of-thrones, age

What was the exact age of Theon Greyjoy when he was brought to live in Winterfell with the Starks? How old was he when he was taken hostage? The age of 10 comes to my mind, but I'm not sure that this is correct.

Comment: If you're also interested in books, you can [edit] your question to add the `asoiaf` tag.

Comment: I've removed the `[characters]` tag as if we include it here we'll have to include it on every question that's ever talked about a character. It should be taken to meta and it's usage discussed there before being added to random questions.

Comment: Fine with me. I added it before because it seemed fitting; the tag description is not very clear about the supposed scope, and other questions labeled with it don't seem to have a common subject rather than generically asking about, well, characters.

Answer (score 13):

Since you have asked this question for the Show, In Showverse, Theon was 8 years old when he was taken by Lord Stark to Winterfell.

> **Theon**: I'm a Greyjoy. We've been lords of the Iron Islands for 300 years. There's not a family in Westeros that can look down on us, not
>   even the Lannisters.
>
> **Ros<sup>1</sup>**: And what about the Starks?
>
> **Theon**: I've been Lord Stark's ward since **I was eight years old**.
>
> **Ros**: A ward - that's a nice word for it.
> <sub>**Season 1 Episode 5 - The Wolf and the Lion**</sub>

[HBO Viewers Guide](http://viewers-guide.hbo.com/game-of-thrones/season-7/episode-7/histories/5/the-greyjoy-rebellion) also confirms it:

> As punishment and to ensure there would be no other uprisings, Robert
>   forced Balon to surrender his only surviving son, Theon (then 8), for
>   Ned Stark to raise as his ward at Winterfell.

---

<sub>1. Name corrected from Rose to Ros, thanks to [Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57310/skooba)</sub>

Answer (score 9):

According to the novels, he was ten years old when he was brought to Winterfell.

> "I was a boy of ten when I was taken to Winterfell as a ward of Eddard Stark."
>   <sub>*A Clash of Kings - Theon I*</sub>